# Debian Buster w/ Overclocking

Tags: pi-4, debian, config.txt, bootloader

Due to software requirements I'm running Debian Buster and am hoping to be able to give my Pi4 a slight overclock. I've created a confix.txt file in /boot with the following content:

```
over_voltage=2
arm_freq=1750
```

However, this doesn't appear to be having any affect. neofetch stil shows `CPU: (4) @ 1.500GHz`

and

```
lscpu | grep MHz
```

gives

```
CPU max MHz:         1500.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
```

I don't seem to be able to find any references to overclocking a pi in Debian (buster) but several indicating that the above `config.txt` in `/boot` should be sufficient.

I've seen suggestions that `/boot` sometimes isn't the first partition that is read by the system on some OS' and that the Pi GPU takes the `config.txt` only from the first partition.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `over_voltage=over_voltage=2` a typing error?  Overclock does not work if you have any power warnings https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md covers buster.

Comment: @Andyroo No it wasn't. But, I've fixed that now and still no change after rebooting the system. Thanks.

Comment: The overclocking from `config.txt` is the same regardless of OS because it is done before the OS is loaded and cannot be changed while the device is running.

Comment: @goldilocks Ok, so then the questions remains, where this needs to be placed on a Debian Buster system since this the current location of /dev/boot/config.txt usn't having any effect. Therefore it seems that /dev/boot isn't the first partition being read by the GPU.

Comment: Never seen anything other than /boot/config.txt read - Do you have the lines in a section not executed by the PI 4?  Feel free to drop the whole of config.txt (minus lines starting with #) into a code block :-)

Comment: Ditto Andyroo.  You actually don't mention this anywhere other than that comment, so perhaps it is something typo-esque but regardless, `/dev/boot/` is a totally bogus path.  When the system **is running**, the first partition is conventionally mounted on `/boot` (although it actually doesn't need to be mounted at all and is only accessed by the system to perform kernel and base firmware updates).  When it isn't, it's the first partition on the card...the format of the card is fairly specific and a requirement of the hardware, so that is again true regardless of OS.

Comment: @Andyroo That literally is the full contents of my config.txt since there wasn't anything in there by default.

Comment: @goldilocks I actually meant /boot sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Another issue there would be using `/boot` when that partition isn't mounted for some reason.  Confirm it's there: `mount  | grep boot`.  If it is, umount it (`sudo umount /boot`) and check there isn't a `config.txt` there.  If there is, at some point either when the system was running or when the SD card was in another machine you wrote `/boot/config.txt` to the second partition...

Comment: But (as confusing as it may be), on unix style systems mounted filesystem are in a hierarchy rooted at `/`, and *mountpoints are always directories*, meaning if you treat the mount point and the directory as synonymous you are likely to end up putting stuff in the directory when nothing is mounted there.   This will just end up hidden when something is mounted there.

Comment: @goldilocks ```mount | grep boot´´´ give me this: /dev/mmcblk1p1 on /boot/firmware type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: @PhillHealey config.txt has lots of things in it by default from the Pi guys. Think your OS install is a bit mixed up - I would have expected `/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type...` or `/dev/sda1 on /boot type` for USB based OS.

Comment: @goldilocks I think you are mistaking my OS. I'm running Debian Buster not Raspbian/RaspberryPiOS. Regardless, I've mounted the sdcard on my PC and found a config.txt file in the root of that which is different to the one I was editing on the Pi itself. It appears that the drive /boot accesssed via SSH is different from the actual boot partition of the SDCard. After updaating the confg.txt in the boot partition I'm now seeing the overclocked speeds in neofetch. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing I've said is Raspbian specific other than "the first partition is conventionally mounted on /boot", which is probably a wider convention than that (but as per my answer, not necessarily so and perhaps not the wisest choice to start with).

Comment: @goldilocks My point was in reference to you saying "config.txt has lots of things in it by default from the Pi guys" ehich isn't true on anything other than Rasbian/RaspberryPi OS. I'm using Debian for Pi.

Comment: That was @Andyroo -- but looks like I never finished that last comment: I wasn't just nitpicking/being defensive, I meant to add that in future you might want to make it explicit in your question (explicit as in literally, "I'm running Debian Buster not...") that by "Debian buster" you don't mean Raspbian/RpiOS, since it is just too easy to be confused by that here, even when "Debian buster" is clearly in the title etc.

Comment: @goldilocks Apologies it was indeed Andyroo. However, the questrion is tagged "Debian" and the question title explicitly says "Debian". At no point do I make any reference to Raspbian / Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Very true, but because Raspbian more or less is Debian,  the former stays in step with the latter version/package wise, and many Pi users are new to linux and aren't familiar with the way linux distribution works, and we get few questions *actually* about Debian-not-Raspbian (have a look at some of the questions with that tag and note that frequently they are in fact about Raspbian -- this should have been fixed when they were asked, but it is a detail that easily slips through the cracks) what I think easily pops here for many people is simply "Buster".

Comment: ...So while you've done nothing wrong, it wouldn't hurt to remember this and nip that confusion in the bud by simply spelling out in a few words something that ideally would be obvious, but for various real world reasons may not be.   Think a difference between "correct" and "better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `mount | grep boot` give me this: `/dev/mmcblk1p1 on /boot/firmware type vfat ...`

The boot partition doesn't actually have to be mounted on the `/boot` directory when running<sup>1</sup>, and in fact it was probably a bad choice on behalf of Raspbian (the wisest choice IMO would have been a special dedicated subdirectory, eg. `/boot/raspberry`).  Anyway, `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is the partition you want, so if it is being mounted on `/boot/firmware`, the you should regard `/boot/firmware` as synonymous with Raspbian centric discussions of `/boot`.  That's where your original `config.txt` would be (although it actually need not exist), and/or where you should put one if you want it to be applied.

Chances are you will see a listing corresponding to this in `/etc/fstab`.

---

1. As mentioned in a previous comment the first partition doesn't need to be mounted at all, except for updating the contents and configuration there.  Although the kernel image is stored and loaded from there, nothing in it is used by the OS.

   On actual Raspbian/RpiOS you should keep it as `/boot` and leave it mounted, since `apt` updates the firmware and kernel in it.

Comment: Yes, `/boot/firmware` is the effective "boot" partition